# Graphical interpretation of sequential definition of continuity (of a function)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a question about arguing as to the discontinuity, of this function, at $x_{0}$, using the sequential definition of continuity. My understanding is that this argument is as follows:

There exists a sequence, $\{x_{n}\}$, converging to $x_{0}$ from the left. However, $f(x_{n})$ does not converge to $f(x_{0})$. Thus, $f$ is not continuous at $x_{0}$.

I would simply write this as $\lim f(x_n)>f(x_{0}).$ However, in my textbook, it is written as $\lim \inf f(x_{n})>f(x_{0})$. What is the significance of the $\inf$ operator? And is my notation incorrect? Thank you.

(Also, as an aside: in my understanding, there is no sequence, converging to $x_{0}$, from the *right*, that could serve to disprove the continuity of $f$ at $x_{0}$. This is because $f(x_{n})$ would indeed, in this case, converge to $f(x_{0})$, and so we would not have a counterexample to the sequential definition of continuity. Is this correct?)

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $f$ is not continuous then $\lim f(x_n)$ need not converge. $\liminf f(x_n)$ however always converges (possibly to $-\infty$).

Take for example the function $f(x)=\cos(1/x)$ and the sequence $x_n=1/(\pi n)$.

Comment: Why couldn't we have written that $\lim \sup f(x_{n})>f(x_{0})$? Why was $\inf$ chosen?